# guava rate limiter sending more qps

Tags: java

I am using guava rate limiter to limit the messages sent 5000 per second. I am achieving the good results but sometimes when guava rate limiter sends fewer records in one second then remaining is sending in another second, let's say in 1 seconds it sends 1000 messages and in another second it sends 9000 messages, but I need to send only 5K messages in every second. if it sends 2000 messages in one second in another second it shouldn't cross 5k, I have to use the previous 3k messages and other 2K messages needs to add for the current second. The code used is as below

```
RateLimiter limiter = RateLimiter.create(5000.0);

for (int i = 0; i < msisdnSize; i++) {limiter.acquire();//sends message}

tried this as well

limiter.acquire();
for (int i = 0; i < msisdnSize; i++) { //sends message }
```

in both the scenarios I haven't achieved the desired QPS

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `//sends message` comment in the first example implies that your actual program has code sending the message where that comment is, then I think the first example looks correct.

Not sure what the issue is, the following groovy code which is functionally more or less identical to your first case:

```
@Grab('com.google.guava:guava:20.0')
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter

long start = System.currentTimeMillis()
long count = 0
RateLimiter limiter = RateLimiter.create(5000.0)
while (true) {
  limiter.acquire()
  count++
  long now   = System.currentTimeMillis()
  long delta = now - start
  if (delta >= 1000) {
    println "sent $count messages in ${delta}ms"
    count = 0
    start = now
  }
}
```

(the code runs an infinite loop calling acquire each iteration and printing the number of iterations once a second) 
gives the following output:

```
    sent 4958 messages in 1000ms
    sent 5001 messages in 1000ms
    sent 5002 messages in 1000ms
    sent 5003 messages in 1001ms
    sent 5004 messages in 1000ms
    sent 4996 messages in 1000ms
    sent 5004 messages in 1000ms
    sent 5001 messages in 1001ms
    sent 5003 messages in 1000ms
    sent 5003 messages in 1001ms
    sent 5002 messages in 1000ms
```

i.e., because of the way the RateLimiter is designed (the acquire after an expensive operation pays the price), the code will at times exceed the limit but in general stay more or less around the correct number.

My guess would be there is something else affecting your numbers. Could it for example be that you are counting the number of completed requests?

In other words, the rate limiter lets you make 5000 requests second one and 5000 requests second two, but if the server handling the requests on the other side just queues them up and responds to all 10000 in second three (and you are counting completed requests), that could well give you the impression that the rate limiter is broken.

Just my 2c and not a conclusive answer by any means.